# Magento2 coding standard public interface

Tags: magento2, coding-standards

According to coding standard protected function should not be used, so i have changed from protected to public then,

I am getting this warning from coding standard,

> Warning: The use of public non-interface method in ACTION is discouraged.

The code is,

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('frontname_namespace::orders');
}
```

I changed to

```
public function _isAllowed()
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('frontname_namespace::orders');
}
```

Anyone have any idea about this ..

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are talking about a class inheriting from "`\Magento\Backend\App\Action`", you should delare it as **protected**, since you are extending a class that declares it as protected (see: `\Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction`).

In this case you should ignore the "protected discouraged" message since is a Magento core class using it.

If you are going to create a **new class** not inheriting from any other Magento core class, then you should always follow the rule "**private over protected**", since class extension is disencouraged and, in that case, class composition is the right way.

Comment: yes,  i am extending \Magento\Backend\App\Action this class.according to coding standard we should not use protected function.so i have found another way to declare that function. now its working fine. i just used acl.xml

Comment: You should avoid using protected methods only when you can. If you are extending a Magento core class, sometimes you must use it.

Comment: @chris, How did you solve this issue? You said that you found another way to declare that function. How did you declare that function?

Comment: @DineshYadav use acl.xml

Answer (score 0):

create the file acl.xml inside /var/wwww/html/magento2/Module/Name/etc/acl.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                    <resource id="Module_Name::orders" title="Orders" sortOrder="51">
            </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </config>
```